# Electromagnetic Induction with liquid conductor

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

If a conductor is moved in a magnetic field current is induced in that conductor. So if I use Liquid mercury in place of the conductor will the same happen?

Answer (score 1):

More precisely an electromotive force is induced across the ends of the conductor because of charge separation due to the magnetic field. The same will happen with liquid mercury.